# How to make a cumulative sum ignore negative numbers in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am considering data that pertains to a battery system where data in excel cells is the amount of charge added in a time period. What I want is a sum that will essentially give me the amount of charge left in the battery, but if the sum is negative I want it to be zero until it receives more charge. How would I do this for a large dataset in Excel?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `MAX()` function to keep the result positive or 0:

```
MAX(<your calculation here>, 0)
```

So for your example (assuming 'charge' is cell A1):

```
charge  sum
   1    =A2
   1    =MAX(A3+B2,0)
   2    =MAX(A4+B3,0)
  -5    =MAX(A5+B4,0)
   1    =MAX(A6+B5,0)
```

Results in:

```
charge  sum
   1      1
   1      2
   2      4
  -5      0
   1      1
```

Apart from the first summation, the formula is consistent so you can fill/repeat it for any size data set.

Answer (score 0):

Use Sum inside the Max as suggested by Mike Fitzpatrick and you can start with this formula in B2 and copy down.

```
=MAX(SUM(A2,B1),0)
```

Sum() ignores text, and you don't need to take precautions for the first row of the formula.